# How to select equal values one time from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table structure like this:

```
|ID | Country | League |
| 0 | Germany | B1     |
| 1 | Germany | B2     |
| 2 | Italy   | A      |
```

How can I get Germany only once with a query? I would like something like this:

```
Germany, Italy.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM some_table
```

This will give you all countries only once.

If you want all country names in a single result, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country ORDER BY country DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS country_list
FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Either select `distinct` values

```
select distinct country 
from your_table
```

or group by the value that should be unique

```
select country 
from your_table 
group by country
```